# What is this plant with hardened fruits on the beach in Mozambique?

Tags: species-identification, fruit

We saw these near the Barra and Tofinho beaches in the Inhambane province in Mozambique, in July. They were hard and leathery and dry to the touch, long past something resembling edible fruit.

Anybody have an idea what they might be? (just curious)

[image: hard beachy fruits]

Edited: Here is some context around the tree.

[image: beachy context]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take a guess that it is *Ficus racemosa* which is found in that area. More [info](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_racemosa). If you have pictures of the rest of the tree that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a context image, and one can see that they are indeed clustered around a trunk, as with *Ficus racemosa*.

Comment: Interesting.  Looks to be a very small specimen or one that is broke-off and making its last stand (my first thought was "where is the rest of the tree?).  These can be very large trees but maybe it is in an exposed area and relatively small or young.